# Function to take a list of integers and count the highest repeated value

Tags: python, arrays, list

Need a function to take a list of integers and return the highest repeated value.

For example: take [4, 2, 2, 2, 8, 5, 4, 2, 9, 6, 3, 2] and return (2,5) because there are 5 copies of the value 2.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service.   You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer for solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this pretty easily using Counter.

```
from collections import Counter

a = [4, 2, 2, 2, 8, 5, 4, 2, 9, 6, 3, 2]

def count_duplicates(list_of_integers):
  a = Counter(list_of_integers)
  return a.most_common()[0]

count = count_duplicates(a)

print(count)
```

The output from that gives you (2, 5)

Answer (score 1):

Inbuilt `max`, `set` and `count` methods:

```
def countMax(arr):
    item = max(set(arr), key=arr.count)
    return (item, arr.count(item))

print(countMax([4, 2, 2, 2, 8, 5, 4, 2, 9, 6, 3, 2]))
```

Prints `(2, 5)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `defaultdict` to achieve this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def highest_repeated_value(nums):
  cache = defaultdict(int)
  for i in nums:
    cache[i] += 1
  return max(cache.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])


nums = [4, 2, 2, 2, 8, 5, 4, 2, 9, 6, 3, 2]
print(highest_repeated_value(nums))
```

Please note that if `nums = [4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2, 8, 5, 4, 2, 9, 6, 3, 2]` then there are `five 4s` and `five 2s`. However, the result will be `(4, 5)` i.e. `five 4s`.

If your using `numpy` and list contains all non-negative `ints`, you can use `numpy.bincounts`:

```
import numpy

def highest_repeated_value(nums):
    counts = numpy.bincount(nums)
    num = numpy.argmax(counts)
    val = numpy.max(counts)
    return num, val

nums = [4, 2, 2, 2, 8, 5, 4, 2, 9, 6, 3, 2]
print(highest_repeated_value(nums))
```

If you just want to work in python without using `numpy`, `collections.Counter` is a good way to handle it.

```
from collections import Counter

def highest_repeated_value(nums):
  return Counter(nums).most_common()[0]

nums = [4, 2, 2, 2, 8, 5, 4, 2, 9, 6, 3, 2]
print(highest_repeated_value(nums))
```

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish this using numpy?

Answer (score 0):

We can utilize tuple to keep track the highest repeated value, like so:

```
def find_highest_repeated(input_list):
    counter = {}
    highest_repeated = (0, 0, )

    for item in input_list:
        counter[item] = counter[item] + 1 if counter.get(item) is not None else 1
        if counter[item] > highest_repeated[1]:
            highest_repeated = (item, counter[item], )

    return highest_repeated

find_highest_repeated([4, 2, 2, 2, 8, 5, 4, 2, 9, 6, 3, 2]) # (2, 5)
```

Hope that helps!